# Single album in UIImagePickerViewController

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm new in iOS development and I was wondering if is possible to use an UIImagePickerViewController to view a single album created by the same 
application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UIImagePickerController will open up to the Albums view, it's then up to the user to decide what album they wish to navigate to.

For an "Album" made by your application, you can create your own "gallery view" and only display the images that your app has created.

Comment: Thks WrightsCS. 
This is exactly what I would not want to read =(
I'll probably do my own "gallery view" with a table view. But if anyone want other solution, I found this tutorial:

[How to Write a Custom Image Picker like UIImagePicker](http://www.raywenderlich.com/130/how-to-write-a-custom-image-picker-like-uiimagepicker)